# How to return the number of occurences of an element on a webpage

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress

On a webpage there are a number of images that appear .img
I was wondering how to get the number of images that appear and return that as a variable to use for other tests

I had this written, but this does not produce anything, just an empty variable

```
cy.get('.img').then(($img) => {
   cy.wrap($img).its('length').then((val)=>{
      return val;
   });
})
```

How can I return the number of occurences (without using any assertions like should have length)? Other solutions I tried produced sync/async errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use the length value for other tests in the same test suite or in other test suites, you can save the value in `Cypress.env` and then use it wherever you want like this:

```js
cy.get('.img')
  .its('length')
  .then((len) => {
    Cypress.env('imgLen', len)
  })
```

Then In your test, You can use it like this:

```js
Cypress.env('imgLen')
cy.log(Cypress.env('imgLen')) //logs img length
cy.get('selector').should('have.length', Cypress.env('imgLen')) //Asserts the length
```

Answer (score 2):

You will want to do something like this.

```js
// maybe have this in beforeEach()
cy.get('.img').its('length').as('numImgs')


// later in a test
cy.get('@numImgs') // to get number of occurrences
```